# UIPrintInteractionController error no airprint printers found

Tags: ios, printing

I'm trying to print a PDF file using UIPrintInteractionController on iPad. But it has an error when entering Select Printer. See the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKfZ0.png)

How can I connect to Printer.

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the AirPrint Simulator in iOS Simulator and selecting File -> Printer Simulator.
The iOS simulator is started with Xcode when you run your program. They have to be both on the same network.

Comment: Thanks your answer.But I want to print a PDF file via iPad device directly. Have you any ideas?

Comment: After you start the AirPrint simulator your iPad will see the available printer and can print. The print output will appear as PDF on the computer.

Comment: Thank you. Have any way print a PDF file on iPad device using wireless?